# How does the rendering equation incorporate shadowing

Tags: rendering, shadow

This is how the rendering equation is written in the textbook

$$L(p,\omega) = L_e(p,\omega) + \int f(p,\omega_i,\omega) \, L(p*,-\omega_i)\cos \theta \, d\omega_i$$

which component of this equation handles the shadowing?

Comment: BTW, what is the "*" notation in this formula? I've never seen that in the rendering equation before.

Comment: @NathanReed p* is just a point from another surface, L(p*,-wi) is just the radiance from point p in direction wi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Light that is blocked will mean that $L(p*, -w_i)$ under the integral is 0 plus how much light the blocking object itself reflects.

In other words the shadowing is embedded in the incoming light function.